# segmentation Fault in C String conversion

Tags: c, string

Below is my program for project Euler. I am getting segmentation error when tried to convert a string to number;

```
main()
{
    char me[] = "731671765313306249";
    int counter = 0;
    unsigned int product = 0;
    unsigned int temp = 0;
    char dup_me[5];
    int j = 0;
    printf("\n The String is:%s", me);

    for(counter = 0; counter <= (strlen(me) - 5); counter ++)
    {
        temp = ((int)(me[counter]) * (int)(me[counter + 1]) * (int)(me[counter + 2]) * (int)(me[counter + 3]) * (int)(me[counter + 4]));
        if (product < temp)
        {
            product = temp;
            for(j = 0; j < 4; j ++)
            {

                dup_me[j] = me[counter + j];
                printf("\nThis time: %d", atoi(dup_me[j]));
            }
            dup_me[j+1] = '\0';
        }
    }
    printf("\n The products is ;%Ld", product);
    printf("The producted numbers are:%s", dup_me);
    return 0;
}
```

If I comment this part, it is running fine.

```
printf("\nThis time: %d", atoi(dup_me[j]));
```

I know the product answer is wrong. it is converting character to their ascii values. I need help with this segmentation fault. I need to convert that individula character(number) to integer value

[The codepad link](http://codepad.org/UdC05jHA)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `me[]` might be invalid. If you want to use `me` as a buffer, declare it as `char* me`. By assigning it a blank string, you have effectively just created a string with not storage space in it.

Comment: `me` is probably the source of the trouble; it is the use of `me` that is invalid rather than `me` itself, though.  The array is big enough to hold a single byte; this is not enough to hold any other data in the string.

Comment: Also, this loop is not executing `for(counter = 0; counter <= (strlen(me) - 5); counter ++)`

Since strlen of me is -5, and the condition is 0>-5, it will never run.

Comment: @StevenMorad edited the question. That link should show you that problem is not with me, but with atoi conversion. Please uncomment printf line to run it without any errors.

Comment: Ah I see. Do you mean to do `atoi(dup_me)` atoi takes a CHARACTER STRING. When you do `atoi(dup_me[j]), you are just giving it a single character.

Answer (score 1):

the prototype of the function `atoi` is as follow : `int atoi(const char *nptr)` so it expects a pointer to `char` and you're giving it a `char` so replace this line : `printf("\nThis time: %d", atoi(dup_me[j]))` with this `printf("\nThis time: %d", atoi(&dup_me[j]));` and everything should work fine